# Is there a tuple data structure in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I want to have an 3 item combination like tag, name, and list of values (array) what is the best possible data structure to store such things.

Current I am using dictionary, but it only allows 2 items, but easy traversal using

```
for k, v in dict.iteritems():
```

can we have something similar like:

```
for k, v, x in tuple.iteritems():
```

Comment: Question title is misleading; the answer to the question in the title is simply "yes". The body of the question actually asks for the best structure to store some data, which is a different question.

Comment: -1: "best possible" is meaningless.  Please ask a question that can be answered.  Best for what purpose?  Speed? Storage? Code Complexity?  What?

Comment: sometimes best possible is generic, which means ease of use, the standard way, complexity, unless their is a notable performance issue or speed issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider the [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) type to create tuple-like objects that have fields accessible by attribute lookup.

> `collections.namedtuple(typename, field_names[, verbose])`
>
> Returns a new tuple subclass named typename. The new subclass is used to create tuple-like objects that have fields accessible by attribute lookup as well as being indexable and iterable. Instances of the subclass also have a helpful docstring (with typename and field_names) and a helpful `__repr__()` method which lists the tuple contents in a name=value format.

```
>>> import collections
>>> mytup = collections.namedtuple('mytup', ['tag','name', 'values'])
>>> e1 = mytup('tag1','great',[1,'two',3])
>>> e1
mytup(tag='tag1', name='great', values=[1, 'two', 3])
>>> e1.values
[1, 'two', 3]
>>>
```

Building on other answers, an example of filtering a list of `mytup` objects:

```
>>> tlist = [mytup("foo", "dog", [1,2,3,4]),
    mytup("bar","cat", [4,5,6,7,8,9]), mytup("moo","cow", [4,5,7,8,9,1,3,4,65])]
>>> tlist
[mytup(tag='foo', name='dog', values=[1, 2, 3, 4]),
mytup(tag='bar', name='cat', values=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
mytup(tag='moo', name='cow', values=[4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 65])]
>>> [t for t in tlist if t.tag == 'bar']
[mytup(tag='bar', name='cat', values=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
>>>
```

`Namedtuple` objects can, of course, be used in other structures (e.g a `dict`), as mentioned in other answers. The advantage is, obviously, that the fields are *named*, and code using them is clearer.

Comment: And how do you create an array of these namedtuple to traversed easily. I am sorry, just started Python yesterday only for writing a Python script.

Comment: List filtering example added.

Comment: `tlist = map(mytup, [("foo", "dog", [1,2]), ("bar", "cat", [3,4]),])`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian this is wrong not working: TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Comment: @Priyank Bolia: Correct. Replace `map` by `itertools.starmap`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831218/is-there-a-tuple-data-structure-in-python/1842063#1842063

Answer (score 8):

[Python tutorial on data structutres](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) see section 5.3 "Tuples and sequences"

however, if you want to use "name" to index the data, you probably want to use a dictionary that has the string name as key and values are tuple of (tag, [list, of, values]) e.g.

```
  d = 
    { "foo" : ("dog", [1,2,3,4]),
      "bar" : ("cat", [4,5,6,7,8,9]),
      "moo" : ("cow", [4,5,7,8,9,1,3,4,65])
    }

  for name,(tag,values) in d.items():
    do_something()
```

this way also`d["foo"]` will work, just like for any other dictionary.

Comment: This is a better answer than the selected one - it directly shows a solution to the posed question.

Answer (score 4):

why not just use a list of tuples (yes, this is a data type in python, like lists, but immutable):

```
mylistoftuples = [(1, 2, 3), (2, "three", 4), (3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
for k, v, x in mylistoftuples:
    print k, v, x
```

Comment: Just for completeness, let's note that this fails badly in the item-lookup department.

Comment: I agree. See Kimvais below for a solution to that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a comment to [@gimel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831218/is-there-a-tuple-data-structure-in-python/1831334#1831334):

```
>>> import collections
>>> T = collections.namedtuple("T", 'tag name values')
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(T, [("a", "b", [1,2]), ("c", "d",[3,4])]))
[T(tag='a', name='b', values=[1, 2]), T(tag='c', name='d', values=[3, 4])]
```

Comment: working good and short to write, but somehow I prefer the gimel method, which looks more clean to read, though much more typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of 3-item tuples.

```
arr = [ (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
for (k, v, x) in arr:
  # do stuff
```